# Custom redirection rules on S3 returns 403 when using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a custom redirection rule for my bucket on S3:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>example2.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>services/create?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

And my bucket has a proper policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine when I access it via its internal url `http://example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and it redirects me to my other server properly.

However, it doesn't work with my CloudFront setup. When I try to access it directly (`http://example.com/images/dummy.jpg`), I receive a **403 AccessDenied**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, when using the default S3 bucket as the origin - it won't respect the redirection rules.

By default, it tries to use:

`example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`, but you should force it to a custom origin:

`example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` instead.

Once I forced it, it started to work.

Comment: Correct.  [*"On the Create Distribution page, in the Origin Settings section, for Origin Domain Name, type the Amazon S3 static website hosting endpoint for your bucket. For example,* example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

**Note**
*Be sure to specify the static website hosting endpoint, not the name of the bucket."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html)  If you select the bucket from the list, CloudFront connects to the REST endpoint of the bucket, instead of the web site endpoint.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once!  Thank you.

Comment: this was surprisingly hard to find, and absolutely essential given the default behavior when you choose an s3 origin don't give you the website origin

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 403 with a standard S3 redirection, make sure you point to a file in the root directory:

[image]