# CloudFront responds with 403 Forbidden instead of triggering Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Here is a schema of  CDN to resize images and serve them via AWS CloudFront:

[image: Communication diagram]

If an image is not found in the S3 bucket, it issues a **307 Temporary Redirect** (instead of 404) to access Lambda via API Gateway. Lambda resizes the image (based on the original from the S3 bucket) and uploads it into the S3 bucket. The browser gets once again permanently redirected to the S3 bucket with the newly generated image.

When I want to access the same image via CloudFront, I am receiving a **403 Forbidden** error. It comes either from the S3 or CloudFront. As the status indicates, this may have something to do with access rights.

Why does adding CloudFront into the working request chain cause the 403 error?

What works:

```
https://{bucket}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com/100x100/image.jpg

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
x-amz-id-2: xxxx
x-amz-request-id: xxxx
Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:37:12 GMT
Location: https://{gateway}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/prod/resize?key=100x100/image.jpg
Content-Length: 0
Server: AmazonS3

https://{gateway}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/prod/resize?key=100x100/image.jpg

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:37:16 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: xxxx
location: http://{bucket}.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/100x100/image.jpg
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: xxxx
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 {distribution}.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxx

http://{bucket}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com/100x100/image.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: xxxx
x-amz-request-id: xxxx
Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:37:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:37:17 GMT
x-amz-version-id: null
ETag: xxxx
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 20495
Server: AmazonS3
```

What doesn't work:

```
https://{distribution}.cloudfront.net/100x100/image.jpg

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:38:24 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 {distribution}.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxx
```

I've added the S3 bucket as origin into CloudFront

Comment: Do you get the 403 from CloudFront for all objects in the S3 bucket or just for some (e.g. the resized images)?

Comment: Just for the images that need to be resized. Once they've been generated (e.g. 
 calling https://{bucket}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com/100x100/image.jpg directly), the URL https://{distribution}.cloudfront.net/100x100/image.jpg starts working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused by using a REST endpoint (e.g. s3.amazonaws.com) for website-like functionality (redirects, html error messages, and index documents). These features are only provided by the web site endpoints (e.g. bucketname.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html

It confused me because the REST endpoint was offered via autocomplete in the console, when creating the CloudFront distribution. The correct endpoint has to be entered manually.

Comment: There's a second potential hit-and-miss problem with this solution, which you should watch for... a *very* new object in S3 may still trigger the missing object redirection, because immediate consistency for uploads of new objects is not available if the object is requested before it is uploaded.  I have been working towards a solution that not only considers this but also works within some additional constraints, such as avoiding the need for the browser to make requests to more than one domain name (e.g. the API Gateway is behind the original CloudFront distro under a different path).

Comment: There might be a better solution, but this is sufficient for what I'm going for. The redirection error is gone and I don't see negative if consistency checking is not available. It might be, but not in my environment.

Comment: Good deal, +1 for your question and your own solution. 
I just wanted to give you a heads-up of something to be aware of.  In my environment, the image sources are third parties, trading partners with whom I have contractual arrangements, and I don't want to repeatedly fetch and resize the same image to avoid causing any overload issues for them, so the occasional "it's already in S3 from seconds ago yet we unnecessarily repeated the fetch and resize process because the bucket index hadn't yet coalesced" is more of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront also caches 40x 50x status codes coming from S3 (doc.: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html#HTTPStatusCodes-cached-errors ).

You should invalidate the Cloudfront cache for the resized img path. You can do it by calling the CreateInvalidation API from your Lambda function.

Doc:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-api

Comment: But at first the problem is to find out where the 403 comes from. Based on the log, the https://{distribution}.cloudfront.net/100x100/image.jpg doesn't even trigger the Lambda function. Therefore, no images are being resized.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752202/custom-redirection-rules-on-s3-returns-403-when-using-cloudfront